# Plot Projects - plotFilterNotifications not getting triggered in objective c (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot

**Initialization of plot is done successfully and latitude and longitude is also getting printed in debug log.**

**- Plot Project below methods not working properly, Particular Location wise trigger is not working. Please suggest to me.**

```
-(void)plotFilterNotifications:(PlotFilterNotifications*)filterNotifications {
NSArray* notifications = filterNotifications.uiNotifications;
for (UNNotificationRequest* notification in notifications) {

    //alter notification
    //ensure the keys in the userInfo also present in the new object.
    NSString* customMessage = @"Custom message";
    UNMutableNotificationContent* customContent =  [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    customContent.body = customMessage;
    NSMutableDictionary* userInfo = [notification.content.userInfo mutableCopy];
    customContent.userInfo = userInfo;
    UNNotificationRequest* updatedNotification =  [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:notification.identifier content:customContent trigger:notification.trigger];
    [updatedNotifications addObject: updatedNotification];
}
// Always call showNotifications at the end of the method
[filterNotifications showNotifications:updatedNotifications];
```

}

```
-(void)plotHandleGeotriggers:(PlotHandleGeotriggers*)geotriggerHandler {
    NSMutableArray* toPass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (PlotGeotrigger* geotrigger in geotriggerHandler.geotriggers) {
        if ([@"pass" isEqualToString:[geotrigger.userInfo objectForKey:PlotGeotriggerDataKey]]) {
            [toPass addObject:geotrigger];
        }
    }
    // Always call markGeotriggersHandled at the end of the method
    [geotriggerHandler markGeotriggersHandled:toPass];
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a copy of the snippets from [the documentation](https://www.plotprojects.com/documentation/#iOS_Filter). It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve and why the following snippets don't work.

Comment: - This function is not work and not fire in update notification :                                                                                                   
     [updatedNotifications addObject: updatedNotification];
}
// Always call showNotifications at the end of the method
[filterNotifications showNotifications:updatedNotifications];